# SQL QUERY to display NULL values when using COUNT

Tags: sql-server

I need to produce the number of healthclub members that are enrolled through their employer(several different employers not just 1) for a monthly membership and what level of membership they have plus their family members. The problem I am having is that currently we do not have any LEVEL D membership but may in the future.  I need the report to display ‘0’ when there is no membership. I tried

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) + 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS
```

And it did not work, any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT
    MEMBERSHIP_TYPE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) AS NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_RELATION = ‘FAMILYMEMBER’ THEN 1 END) AS FAMILY_MEMBERS,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) + COUNT(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_RELATION    ‘FAMILY_MEMBERS’ THEN 1 END) AS TOTAL
```

This is what I currently get

```
MEMBERSHIP_TYPE  NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS    FAMILY_MEMBERS  TOTAL
-------------------------------------------------------------
LEVEL A                 100                  25           125
LEVEL B                 630                 340           970
LEVEL C                1201                 630          1831
```

I need this

```
MEMBERSHIP_TYPE  NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS    FAMILY_MEMBERS  TOTAL
-------------------------------------------------------------
LEVEL A                 100                  25           125
LEVEL B                 630                 340           970
LEVEL C                1201                 630          1831
LEVEL D                   0                   0             0
```

Comment: For some reason the formatting is lost when I try to post the table but these are the columns   MEMBERSHIP_TYPE,NUMBER_ OF_CUSTOMERS,  FAMILY_MEMBERS, and  TOTAL.  The rows with the different levels are below:
LEVEL  A   
LEVEL  B   
LEVEL  C   
LEVEL  D

Comment: is there a master table of the levels?

Answer (score 0):

You will hardcode the value into the select statement. Add a UNION ALL to the SQL statement

```
..your current select statement
UNION
SELECT LEVEL D, 0,0,0;
```

When an entry of Level D will be made in the table, the updated value will be shown correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I decided just to run the query using the Level D criteria and nothing came up, so I then I started commenting out each line in the where clause and ran the query each time I commented  out a line. It wasn't until I got to the line regarding the member term date >=GETDATE() and ran the query and got the LEVEL D line, however these are all members that terminated prior to today and I need the term date to filter out the rest of the levels of membership so that terminated members are not included in the counts.   So that is my new problem.